# How to stop Vue.js from selecting the first option in select option?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

My Vue/Buefy app automatically selects the first option from the list:

```
<b-select model="form.cities[i].index"
    v-on:input.once="analyt('City ' + i)"
    @input="form.cities[i].name = cities[form.cities[i].index ['@attributes'].Name"
    :id="'city-'+i"
    :name="'city-'+i"
    :required="i == 0"
>
    <option
        :value="index"
        v-for="(city,index) in cities"
        v-text="city['@attributes'].Name">
    </option>
</b-select>
```

How do I avoid that? I just want empty field selected by default (or nothing to be selected at all)

Comment: this.cities.unshift({['@attributes']:'please select city'})

Comment: What's `model="form.cities[i].index"`? Is is v-model?

Comment: Did you tried `<b-select :value="null" ...` ?

Comment: @talkhabi yes, it doesn't work

Comment: There is multiple issues in your code.
`on:input.once` - did you mean `v-on:input.once`? Also. your tag `name ` includes a addition operator (+) that does not work without `:` in-front. props without colon returns as strings

Comment: Also, if you correct the `v-on:`, you are listening to input event twice, since `v-on:` and `@` is the same thing. please read: [Vue shorthands](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand)

Comment: @SølveTornøe yes i know it's on purpose. i omitted all this when copying/pasting the code. will fix it now. thanks!

Comment: Does `form.cities[i].index` init as 0?

Comment: @DanielBeck what is 'init as 0'?

Comment: When the component first loads, does that variable contain the value "0"?   You're using `v-model` so the selected option should be whatever matches the content of the variable you're `v-model`ing.

Comment: (Actually now that I look, you're just using "model".  Is that a typo in the question, or is it that way in your code as well?  If so, correct it to `v-model`.)

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add an empty option field? This should solve your problem.

```
<b-select model="form.cities[i].index"
          v-on:input.once="analyt('City ' + i)"
          @input="form.cities[i].name = cities[form.cities[i].index ['@attributes'].Name"
          :id="'city-'+i"
          :name="'city-'+i"
          :required="i == 0"
>
    <option selected></option>
    <option
            :value="index"
            v-for="(city,index) in cities"
            v-text="city['@attributes'].Name">
    </option>
</b-select>
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. It looks like vue is automatically selecting an option with value=0 but i can't find the place in Vue script where it's set.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by making sure the first element in the populating array was my default (the one I wanted selected). Then I set the `value` of the `select` element to the default.

In my case, I was populating the drop down list based on selection of a different drop down.

First drop down

```
<select id="firstDropdown" @change="populateDropdown">
  // options code ...
</select>
```

Drop down being populated by the first drop down.

```
<select id="populatedDropdown">
  <option v-for:"item in items">
    {{ item }}
  </option>
</select>
```

In Component script

```
data: function() {
  return {
    items: []
  }
},
method: {
  populateDropdown() {
  // fetch items from api and store in "array".
  this.items = ['Default'].concat(array);
  document.querySelector('#popualtedDropdown').value = 0;
}
```

I hope that makes sense and helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option
  value="none" selected disabled hidden> 
</option>
```

This worked for me seamlessly.

Another option is

```
<option
  selected> 
</option>
```

which gives an empty first entry in the list which is a bit undesired.

Comment: Consider providing some explanation how and why your code should work.